# java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet closed when updating based on the order of definition in the main class

Tags: java, database, sqlite, connection

I have a class which will connect to its own SQLite database and has functions to interact with the database. There are two instances of this class in my code `customerDB` and `merchantDB`. For some reason, the instance that is defined first in the main class will throw an error if I try to call the `addBalance();` or `reduceBalance();` function **after the definition of the other instance of the class**.

The error I get in this instance is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet closed

And when I originally tried to call `addBalance();` later on in my main program, I got the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: database connection closed

I am using the JBDC library in my Java program, and the `users` table inside the database has exactly the same layout for both databases. Any help would be appreciated.

`Users.db`

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class UsersDB {
    private static Connection conn = null;
    
    private boolean loggedIn = false;
    private boolean merchant = false;
    private String username;
    private float balance;
    
    public UsersDB(String dbName, boolean merchant) {
        this.merchant = merchant;
        // try to connect to DB
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + dbName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error - " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    public void login(String username, String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, SQLException {
        
        // Check the fields contain data and that the user is not already logged in
        if (!Util.isNullOrEmpty(username) && !Util.isNullOrEmpty(password) && loggedIn == false) {
            ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" + username + "'");
            
            // Check if username exists
            if (rs.next()) {
                String passwordInDB = rs.getString("password");
                
                MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
                byte[] passwordHash = digest.digest(password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                
                // Check if passwords match
                if (Util.bytesToHex(passwordHash).equals(passwordInDB)) {
                    loggedIn = true;
                    
                    this.username = username;
                    balance = rs.getFloat("balance");
                    System.out.println("Successful login, " + this.username);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Incorrect Username or Password");
            }
            
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, there was an error logging in!");
        }
    }
    
    public float getBalance() throws SQLException {
        if (loggedIn) {
            ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" + username + "'");          
            return rs.getFloat("balance");          
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Action may not be performed. User must be logged in.");
        }
        return 0;
    }
    
    public void reduceBalance(float price) throws Exception {
        // User must be logged in to update balance
        // Price must be valid and not exceed the user's balance
        if (loggedIn && price > 0 && getBalance() >= price) {
            float newBalance = balance - price;
            conn.createStatement().executeUpdate("UPDATE users SET balance = " + newBalance + " WHERE username = '" + username + "'");
            // Update the value of balance to the new once stored in the database
            balance = getBalance();
            if (balance != newBalance) {
                throw new Exception("Balance Update Failed");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Customer balance decreased by " + price);
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Cannot reduce balance");
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
    
    public void addBalance(float price) throws Exception {
        if (loggedIn && price > 0) {
            float newBalance = balance + price;
            conn.createStatement().executeUpdate("UPDATE users SET balance = " + newBalance + " WHERE username = '" + username + "'");
            // Update the value of balance to the new once stored in the database
            balance = getBalance();
            if (balance != newBalance) {
                throw new Exception("Balance Update Failed");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Cannot add balance");
        }
    }
    
    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return loggedIn;
    }
    
    public boolean isMerchant() {
        return merchant;
    }
    
    public void closeConnection() throws SQLException {
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

`Definition`

```
UsersDB merchantDB = new UsersDB("Merchants.db", true);
        merchantDB.login("merchant", "merchantpass");
        // Works
        merchantDB.addBalance(20);
        
        UsersDB customerDB = new UsersDB("Customers.db", false);
        customerDB.login("test", "testpass");   
        
        // Does not work
        merchantDB.addBalance(20);
```

Comment: Post the error message that you get.

Comment: @forpas I have updated the question to include error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the connection as static:

```
private static Connection conn = null;
```

This means that all instances of the class `UsersDB` will use the same connection.

Remove the keyword `static` from its definition.

Comment: I can't believe I did not see this - this explains why the error message changed to connection closed after closing the connection with customerDB. Thanks.